# Does the .NET version on my PC interfere on how SQL queries are processed?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, mysql-error-1064

I have a SQL server running on a virtual machine in my Win 7 host. I also have a C# class that make some queries. It all worked fine, until I installed a new version of .NET, now the query doesn't gives me error but the values are passed as nulls to the database (I already tried inserting with and without injections treatment). So, my question is, can the .NET version be the reason for that?

here is some coding in C#

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, this.DBConnection);
for (int i = 0; i < _values.Count(); i++)
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par" + i.ToString(), _values[i]);
}
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is how I'm trying to insert data.

Comment: What exactly you are using, You are using MySql in code and you are saying SQL server in question ?

Comment: And you might want to take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You have conflicting tags.  Are you using _Sql Server_ or _MySql_?  Also, does MySql support named parameters?

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the article sir.
I might have expressed myself poorly, I am using MySql coding. The problem is that when I try to insert data as shown above I get the error saying that one of my collumns can't be null (that happens because this column is edited in a way not to accept null data). 
What I don't understand is why this is happening, I don't think my code is wrong (or is it?)
Also, sorry for the miss usage of tags.